# Is it more secure if I separate VPS into WebApp/MySQL VPS & separating WebApp projects into Admin/User projects

Tags: server, mysql, virtualization, laravel

If I want to deploy a Laravel WebApp using MySQL DB on a VPS like DigitalOcean, Vultr or similar platforms, should I separate the VPS into WebApp VPS and MySQL VPS? Is it more secure?

And what if I separate the Laravel project into AdminProject and UserProject but use the same MySQL DB and VPS. Is it more secure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, for the first part, separating systems could improve security since a compromise of one doesn't immediately result in the other being compromised. That said, if your web application server is compromised and has readable database credentials sitting around, an attacker could pivot to the database anyway.

For the second part, I see no issue with using the same database server for both as long as each project users its own set of unprivileged credentials for the database. This way, even if one of the web applications is compromised, the other project's data won't be accessible.

There is one downside to splitting up into multiple VPSes: complexity. If you were running all services on the same host, you could just have the database listen on localhost only and not worry about securing it from the network. However, if the database runs on a separate server, you will need to expose it to the network, ensuring it is properly restricted with access controls, firewall rules, and possibly encryption.